# Building an AOSP app that uses shared libraries

Tags: android, build, keyboard, android-source, android-library

How could it be possible to build an AOSP app from source (using mma to build so there would only be the needed modules instead of a full system image) and have access to shared libraries?

I'm building LatinIME with some modifications.
As I wanted to easily install and debug, I changed the package name. Now I can easily install the app as user app but it can't access the .so files in system partition. If I try to install the app with original package name, it can't because of the old app installed.

`library "/system/lib64/libjni_latinimegoogle.so" ("/system/lib64/libjni_latinimegoogle.so") needed or dlopened by "/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace`

The other way I could think of is to keep the package name as original but either create a flashable zip or copy the apk each time to system partition.

Is it possible to allow access to this file (or include it in the apk) or do I need to do this the hard way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest path is to have a copy of all needed non-public system native libraries in your APK, under `lib/arm64-v8a` or the other relevant ABI. **libjni_latinimegoogle.so** may depend on other libraries, and you must pack them with your APK, too. Make sure you use the correct versions of these libs. You can pull them from your **system/lib64** via adb.

But replacing the APK in the system partition is a cleaner way to handle the situation. This does involve reboot each time, but I would probably choose this track, to avoid any possible behavioral differences between the system app and the user app.